# Iterating through Filtered Array

Tags: javascript

I have a pretty complex JSON data set that I have managed to filter by `serial_number`. However, the hurdle now is that although it is giving me the expected output, it isn't in the form I quite expected as I was under the impression that the output returned would only have one array with the match. However, if the output returned is correct, then any explanation is welcome. Below is the JSON and the code:

JSON

```
[
    {
        "district": "Kolkata",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "6",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0001",
                        "name" : "Mr.A"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0002",
                        "name" : "Mr.B"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0003",
                        "name" : "Mr.C"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0004",
                        "name" : "Mr.D"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "7",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0005",
                        "name" : "Mr.E"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0006",
                        "name" : "Mr.F"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0007",
                        "name" : "Mr.G"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0008",
                        "name" : "Mr.H"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "district": "Hooghly",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "8",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0009",
                        "name" : "Mr.I"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0010",
                        "name" : "Mr.J"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0011",
                        "name" : "Mr.K"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0012",
                        "name" : "Mr.L"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "9",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0013",
                        "name" : "Mr.M"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0014",
                        "name" : "Mr.N"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0015",
                        "name" : "Mr.O"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0018",
                        "name" : "Bruno Fernandes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The code

```
const query = {
        serial_number : "0018"
    };

    const filterData = dummyData.map(value => value.ward_no.map(
        value => {
            if(value.grievance.filter(value => value.serial_number === query.serial_number)) {
                return value.grievance.filter(value => value.serial_number === query.serial_number)
            } else {
                return value.general.filter(value => value.serial_number === query.serial_number)
            }
        }
    ));

    console.log(filterData)
```

The output currently returns nothing:
[image]

As per the query I'm taking i.e `serial_number = 0018`, the output I expect is

```
{
   "serial_number": "0018",
   "name" : "Bruno Fernandes"
}
```

I would also like to know if using the map method would let me iterate through the above properties to be able to display them in elements.

Comment: you data does not match the properties of mapping/filtering. do you have some data which match the code? and do you mind to add this to stacksnippets?

Comment: Note that an array, whether empty or not, is evaluated as `true` in JavaScript so your `if...else` will always return the first option

Comment: @NinaScholz Apologies. I have now edited the code and also the screenshot of the output. Although now, both the results don't have anything in them

Comment: please add a wanted result along with taken search values.

Comment: You need to add `.length` in the `if` since filter will return `[]` which evaluates to true

Comment: @NinaScholz I have added the result and the search values at the end

Comment: do you have always only a single object as result?

Comment: @NinaScholz I was expecting the result to be an array of only one object which makes the match. Instead, I ended up getting two with nothing in them. So I would say only a single array of object should be convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract and flatten the `grievance` and `general` array using `array#flatMap` and then filter on `serial_number` using `array#filter`.

```js
const dummyData = [ { "district": "Kolkata", "ward_no": [ { "ward": "6", "grievance": [ { "serial_number": "0001", "name" : "Mr.A" }, { "serial_number": "0002", "name" : "Mr.B" } ], "general": [ { "serial_number": "0003", "name" : "Mr.C" }, { "serial_number": "0004", "name" : "Mr.D" } ] }, { "ward": "7", "grievance": [ { "serial_number": "0005", "name" : "Mr.E" }, { "serial_number": "0006", "name" : "Mr.F" } ], "general": [ { "serial_number": "0007", "name" : "Mr.G" }, { "serial_number": "0008", "name" : "Mr.H" } ] } ] },{ "district": "Hooghly", "ward_no": [ { "ward": "8", "grievance": [ { "serial_number": "0009", "name" : "Mr.I" }, { "serial_number": "0010", "name" : "Mr.J" } ], "general": [ { "serial_number": "0011", "name" : "Mr.K" }, { "serial_number": "0012", "name" : "Mr.L" } ] }, { "ward": "9", "grievance": [ { "serial_number": "0013", "name" : "Mr.M" }, { "serial_number": "0014", "name" : "Mr.N" } ], "general": [ { "serial_number": "0015", "name" : "Mr.O" }, { "serial_number": "0018", "name" : "Bruno Fernandes"} ] } ] } ],
      query = { serial_number : "0018" },
      filterData = dummyData
        .flatMap(({ward_no}) => ward_no
              .flatMap(o => ['grievance', 'general'].flatMap(k => o[k])))
        .filter(o => o.serial_number === query.serial_number);
console.log(filterData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the nested parts and return either the parts, if the returned array has a length greater than zero.

You coudl take a recursive approach and check every array for an object with the wanted value.

```js
const
    search = o => {
        let result = [];
        Object.entries(o).some(([k, v]) => {
            if (k in query && query[k] === v) return result.push(o);
            if (Array.isArray(v)) {
                const temp = v.flatMap(search);
                if (temp.length) return result.push(...v.flatMap(search));
            }
        });
        return result;
    },
    data = [{ district: "Kolkata", ward_no: [{ ward: "6", grievance: [{ serial_number: "0001", name: "Mr.A" }, { serial_number: "0002", name: "Mr.B" }], general: [{ serial_number: "0003", name: "Mr.C" }, { serial_number: "0004", name: "Mr.D" }] }, { ward: "7", grievance: [{ serial_number: "0005", name: "Mr.E" }, { serial_number: "0006", name: "Mr.F" }], general: [{ serial_number: "0007", name: "Mr.G" }, { serial_number: "0008", name: "Mr.H" }] }] }, { district: "Hooghly", ward_no: [{ ward: "8", grievance: [{ serial_number: "0009", name: "Mr.I" }, { serial_number: "0010", name: "Mr.J" }], general: [{ serial_number: "0011", name: "Mr.K" }, { serial_number: "0012", name: "Mr.L" }] }, { ward: "9", grievance: [{ serial_number: "0013", name: "Mr.M" }, { serial_number: "0014", name: "Mr.N" }], general: [{ serial_number: "0015", name: "Mr.O" }, { serial_number: "0018", name: "Bruno Fernandes" }] }] }],
    query = { serial_number : "0018" },
    result = data.flatMap(search);

console.log(result);
```